# Survival probability (1D Brownian Particle)

Tags: probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Here is an interesting article from Wikipedia:
[First-hitting-time model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model)

I am particularly interested in how the following density is derived:

$$p\left(x,t;x_0,x_c\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi  D t}}\left( e^{-\frac{\left(x-x_c\right){}^2}{4 D t}}-e^{-\frac{\left(x-\left(2 x_c-x_0\right)\right){}^2}{4 D t}}\right)$$

Can anyone provide some hints?